# Django - ModelForm - UpdateView -pk

Tags: django, primary-key

I would like to implement UpdateView in order to update selected objects of my Model.

Currently I have:

views.py

```
def fd_detail(request, fdslug):

   fddetail = Fd.objects.get(slug=fdslug)

   cffilter = CashFlowFilter(request.GET, queryset=CashFlow.objects.filter(feeder__slug=fdslug))

   return render(request, 'fd/fd_detail.html',
    {'fddetail': fddetail,
    'cffilter': cffilter,
   })

class CashFlowUpdate(UpdateView):
 model = CashFlow
 fields = ['amount', 'description']
```

url.py

```
path('<slug:fdslug>/updatecashflow/', views.CashFlowUpdate.as_view(),name = "update_cashflow"),
path('<slug:fdslug>/', views.fd_detail, name="fd_detail")
```

update_cashflow.html

```
<form method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.as_p }}
 <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

I get the following error : " Generic detail view CashFlowUpdate must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf." , which means i need to pass-through the primary key of the object I want to Update... What is the best way to do it? Currently all my objects are displayed via a table (see below)? i could add a column with a url link "Edit", but how to put the pk in it?

```
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      {% for cashflow in cffilter.qs %}
        <tr>
          <td>   {{cashflow.amount}} </td>
          <td>   {{cashflow.description}}  </td>
          <td>   ?????? </td>
        </tr>
      {% empty %}
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5"> No cashflow matches your search criteria</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

many thanks

Comment: `F` is a model here? In Django there is an `F` that basically stands for "field", so in order to avoid "name clashes", it might be better to give your model a more descriptive name.

Comment: Yes that's a Model. Good Point& Ive changed but still same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error says:

> Generic detail view CashFlowUpdate must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

An update view usually needs some kind of URL parameter to determine which object to update. It implicitly aims to check for two fields: the slug and the primary key. But here in your `urls.py`, you used `fdslug` as a URL parameter.

This can easily be resolved by specifying a [**`slug_url_kwarg`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_url_kwarg) yourself, like:

```
class CashFlowUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = CashFlow
    fields = ['amount', 'description']
    slug_url_kwarg = 'fdslug'
```

As for an edit link, you can add a `{% url ... %}` template tag, like:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'update_cashflow' fdslug=cashflow.slug %}">edit</a></td>
```

Comment: Hi Willem. Ok thanks, let me try that. But what would be the solution working with primary key? thanks again

Comment: @TMD: wrell the `pk_url_kwarg` is set by default to `pk`. So you could, instead of a slug, add a `pk` to your URL (or change the value of the `pk_url_kwarg` to the name of the primary key URL parameter).